# Check if an expression is a match with regex

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I have two strings: `[I/text]` and `[S/100x20]`.

So, the first one is `[I/` followed by text and ending in `]`.

And the second is `[S/` followed by an integer, then `x`, then another integer, and ending in `]`.

I need to check if a given string is a match of one of this formats. I tried the following:

```
(?<word>.*?) and (?<word>[0-9]x[0-9])
```

But this does not seem to work and I am missing the `[I/...]` and `[S/...]` parts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Following regex does it. Matches the whole string

```
"(\[I/\w+\])|(\[S/\d+x\d+\])"
```

Comment: i think you got the two examples confused. S/ is followed by digits

Answer (score 0):

This should do nicely:

```
Regex rex = new Regex(@"\[I/[^\]]+\]|\[S/\d+x\d+\]");
```

If the text in `[I/text]` is supposed to include only alphanumeric characters then @Oleg's use of the `\w` instead of `[^\]]` would be better. Also using `+` means there needs to be at least one of the preceding character class, and the `*` allows class to be optional. Adjust as needed..

And use:

```
string testString1 = "[I/text]";
if(rex.IsMatch(testString1))
{
    // should match..
}

string testString2 = "[S/100x20]";
if(rex.IsMatch(testString2))
{
    // should match..
}
```

Comment: I believe there should be \d+ as int is required. And after I/ should be \w+ to match text characters only.

Comment: yeah. you're right about the `\d+`. I'm not sure what the _text_ is supposed to include, that's why I left it as `[^\]]`

Comment: Shouldn't the `*` technically be a `+` since (based how I'm reading the OP) the `text` is expected to be there?

Comment: For the [I/text] I was able to use it as follows: @"\[I/.*?] ... But what is the difference between .*? and ^\ or \w+? I tried by approach and it accepts numbers, letters, punctuation, spaces, ... And it requires at least one character. But what is the difference?

Comment: `\w` matches any character from `a - z`, `0-9` or `_`, whereas `.*?` matches any character, including special characters. Finally `[^\]]` this represents a character class and it matches any character (including symbols) that is not the `]` character. If you want to only match characters fomr `a - z` then you would use `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

([I/\w+])
(S/\d+x\d+])

the above works.

use http://regexr.com?34543 to play with your expressions

Comment: [so] has very good [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code); please take advantage of it.  Also, your second regex is missing the opening `[`.